# My command will not run, even though it is recognised as an executable

Tags: command-line, executable

Here is the command I have typed in order. I expect it to run my "simple hello work" program.

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ ls
    filename.zip  tester
    vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ file -b tester
    ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
    vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ tester
    No command 'tester' found, did you mean:
     Command 'gtester' from package 'libglib2.0-dev' (main)
     Command 'jester' from package 'jester' (universe)
     Command 'testr' from package 'testrepository' (main)
    tester: command not found
```

Comment: Have you tried "./tester"?

Comment: thats it :-| create answer and i will accept, i thought you could just type command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your binary is not in the $PATH variable/environment and therefor not known to the shell.

You need either to call it by using

```
./tester
```

or add it to the path

```
set PATH=$PATH:/path/to/tester
```

To make the the change to the path permanent put this line into your ~/.bashrc

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/tester
```